# Finding it dificult to navigate to another page

Tags: flutter

[This is the screenshot of where the error is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXt6M.png)I tried navigating to another page using Raised button, but kept on getting

```
1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
Try adding the missing arguments.dartnot_enough_positional_arguments
```

This is my code below:

```
RaisedButton(
  splashColor: Colors.red,
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EditDataWidget()),
    );
  },
  child: Text('Edit',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
  color: Colors.blue,
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `EditDataWidget()` is expecting a parameter and you are not passing any.
Open the where that `EditDataWidget()` is declared and what parameter it expects as mandatory in it's constructor.